# Какими словами можно заменить частицу "ну а если"?

Tags: синтаксис, выбор-слов, частица

Какими словами можно заменить частицу "ну а если"? Или как проверить, частица ли это?

Answer (score 1):

Можно заменить словами "**коли/коль [уж]**", "**раз [уж]**".  Кстати, похоже, Вам ответили, что в другом Вашем вопросе "*если, то*" - союз, и только "*ну а*" - частица.